# Python tkinter GUI simple noob question: Is it necessary to use a class for tkinter GUI event handling?

Tags: python, user-interface, button, tkinter, event-handling

When I use a class for my tkinter GUI, seems like I don't have to deal with the order of the declaration of variables and the input parameters of functions. However, the main thing is that, when I don't use a class for my tkinter GUI, I cannot use any event handling for my buttons.

So, is it necessary to use a class for tkinter GUI event handling?

Comment: What do you mean _"when I don't use a class for my tkinter GUI, I cannot use any event handling for my buttons."_ , you can bind on events to the buttons even without using classes, if thats what your asking

Answer (score 0):

No, classes aren't required in order to be able to handle events.

Comment: How about multiple windows? Do I need to create a class or classes to make multiple windows? Again, do I need to create a class or classes to make multiple windows events handling?

Comment: @DeerLawson: no, classes are never required. They make the job easier but aren't required.